# Add conditions on shorthand argument name $0 that returns one or two different text views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, foreach, swiftui

I have the following struck and will like to add some conditions referring to a `func` such as `if conditionName() == $0` is true do this... else... inside the `Button($0) {}` using shorthand argument name `$0` . Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let emojiMoves = ["", "", "✂️"]
    let textMoves = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

    @State private var appChoice = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    @State private var userChoice = Bool.random()

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
            ForEach(self.emojiMoves, id: \.self ) {
                Button($0) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean inside the `Button($0) {}` or instead of ?

Comment: inside Button($0) {} , thank you!

Comment: You can't use shorthand argument of one closure inside another closure, because shorthand refers to own closure only, so to pass argument next you have to use explicitly named argument as answered below.

Comment: @Asperi that is correct, my intention is adding such conditions inside Button($0), I think I have a working solution. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of ternary conditional operator I came to this solution that loads buttons with the shorthand argument name $0 inside `Button` .

```
ForEach(self.emojiMoves, id: \.self ) {
      Button($0 == "" ? "" : $0 == "" ? "" : "✂️") {
     }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot basically and also it is not necessary, you may try use a variable:

```
  ForEach(self.emojiMoves, id: \.self ) { oneString in
            Button(Text(oneString)) {
              if conditionName() == oneString {}
               }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @E.Coms this is a nice solution but I'm looking for something else. I think I have the solution below